# QGIS: Select objects and insert relative attributes in other layer

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

In QGIS I'd like to graphically select multiple objects in one layer and insert corresponding multiple IDs in a unique field of a second layer.
Is that possible with QGIS?
(I'm working with two PostgreSQL/PostGIS tables, the first with geometries and the second without.)

I'll try to explain myself better: in QGIS I'd like to select some points in one layer (with geometries) and copy multiple IDs related in a single field "p_id" of another table (with no geometries) in the form {id1,id2,id3,etc...}, like the following example:

```
+----+------------+------+----------------+
| id | date       | work | p_id           |
+----+------------+------+----------------+
| 1  | 2020-04-01 | 1    | {1,2,3}        |
+----+------------+------+----------------+
| 2  | 2020-05-02 | 2    | {124,512,99,1} |
+----+------------+------+----------------+
| 3  | 2020-12-04 | 1    | {15}           |
+----+------------+------+----------------+
```

Now I would be able to reach this goal by selecting objects, copy-and-paste related ids, separate them by commas, enclose them by curly brackets and write a SQL command to write the values I need in the second table, but I'm asking if I can also insert values starting from a manual graphical selection of objects starting from QGIS

Comment: I feel like you don't exactly know what you want to do (or describe it rather poorly), so how should we know what you want to do and then solve the issue?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to select features from a layer with a geometry. Get the ids of those features, put it in a list and add this list to a field of another layer with no geometries ? How do you know wich list goes with wich feature of the second table ?

Comment: yes @JULESG I want to do exactly what you wrote. I have to manually select features from first layer, and I need to get the list of relates attribute ids to write in a new record already created in second layer in "p_id" column. No automatic matches. I would tell QGIS the list values after graphical selections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution for you but it's in PyQgis.
This is the code to put in the text editor of the python console on Qgis. you need to change the name `layer_to_change` and `table_to_change` in the first two lines and the name of the column `test_to_change` :

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("layer_to_change")[0]
table = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("table_to_change")[0]

def listToString(l):
    str1 = "{"  
    for elem in l:  
        str1 += str(elem)
        if elem != l[-1] :
            str1 = str1 + ", "
        else :
            str1 = str1 + "}"
    return str1  

list_result = []
table.startEditing()
for feature in layer.selectedFeatures():
    list_result.append(feature.id())

str_result = listToString(list_result)


# EDIT EXISTING LINE
for line in table.selectedFeatures():
    table.changeAttributeValue(line.id(), table.fields().indexFromName('test_to_change'), str_result)
# ADD A LINE TO TABLE
feat = QgsFeature(table.fields())
table.addFeature(feat)
table.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), table.fields().indexFromName('test'), str_result)


table.commitChanges()
table.triggerRepaint()
```

You need to add both your layer and postgis table to a Qgis Project:

[image]

Go in the attribute table of your table and select a line you want to modify :

[image]

I want to add the list of ID from the layer in the column "test".

Then select the features you want to add to the list of ID on your map canvas :

[image]

Once you'vs selected the line and the features you can launch the script. This is the result :

[image]

Comment: Gorgeus !!
I'll test it as soon as I can, in the meanwhile....T H A N K  YOU @JULESG

Comment: It comes out this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 63, in runsource
    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 168, in __call__
    return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 99, in _maybe_compile
    raise err1
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 87, in _maybe_compile
    code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)

Comment: File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 133, in __call__
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, 1)
  File "<input>", line 3
    table.commitChanges()
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
table.triggerRepaint()

Comment: @ocelot73
Maybe try to comment the lines :
table.startEditing()
table.commitChanges()
table.triggerRepaint()

and put the table in edition mode before launching the script

Comment: Your code works @JULESG, thanks.

Comment: If I'd need to put selected features' id list in a newly created line in the other table? Can you help me with new code needed?

Comment: @ocelot73 I edited my answer with the code to add list of id to a new line.

Comment: Thanks you very much !!!